# Java Printing on thermal printer cutts off content from either side

Tags: java, printing

I am trying to print content from a bean object to a thermal printer with the code above, it works perfectly on other printers but not on a thermal printer,

Content is cutt-off from either side and only incomplete content placed in the middle of the paper roll is visible.

I am using barbacue to generate a bar-code and draw the image to the graphic as well, 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
package com.iwar.utility;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.Book;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Paper;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import net.sourceforge.barbecue.Barcode;
import net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeException;
import net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeFactory;
import net.sourceforge.barbecue.BarcodeImageHandler;
import net.sourceforge.barbecue.output.OutputException;

import com.iware.connection.db.GetStuff;
import com.iware.pos.beans.PrintableBean;

public class PrinterManager {

public static boolean PrintTicket(final PrintableBean printable, final String input){
    try
    { 

// printable is a bean containing all the information to be printed.

        final Book book = new Book();//java.awt.print.Book
 // here i create a new printable object where draw all the content from the bean         //object onto the graphic g
        Printable b= new Printable() {

            @Override
            public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page)
                    throws PrinterException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // We have only one page, and 'page'
                // is zero-based
                if (page > 0) {
                    return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
                }
                // User (0,0) is typically outside the
                // imageable area, so we must translate
                // by the X and Y values in the PageFormat
                // to avoid clipping.

 //                 Paper paper = pf.getPaper();

                Paper paper = new Paper();

                double paperWidth = 3;//3.25
                double paperHeight = 5;//11.69
                double leftMargin = 0.12;
                double rightMargin = 0.10;
                double topMargin = 0.75;
                double bottomMargin = 0.01;

                paper.setSize(paperWidth * 100, paperHeight * 100);
                paper.setImageableArea(leftMargin * 200, topMargin * 200,
                     (paperWidth - leftMargin - rightMargin) * 200,
                     (paperHeight - topMargin - bottomMargin) * 200);

                pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.PORTRAIT);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g; 

                g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
                g.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Bold", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 10));
                g.drawString("HUB ENTERTAINMENT LIMITED", 0, 25);
                g.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Bold", Font.CENTER_BASELINE, 8)); 
                g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g.drawString("Ticket Number : " + printable.getTicket_entry_number(), 0, 90);
                g.drawString("Ticket Type   : " + printable.getTicket_type(), 0, 110);
                g.drawString("Movie Name    : " + printable.getMovie_name(), 0, 130);
                g.drawString("Date          : " + printable.getShow_date(), 0, 150);
                g.drawString("Time          : " + printable.getSpecific_time(), 0, 170);
                g.drawString("Theater       : " + printable.getTheater(), 0, 190);
                g.drawString("Cinema Room   : " + printable.getCinema_room(), 0, 210);
                g.drawString("Cost          : " + printable.getCost(), 0, 230);
                g.drawString("Cashier       : " + printable.getCashier(), 0, 250);
                g.drawString("Printed On    : " + GetStuff.getCurrentDate(), 0, 270);
                g.drawString("Seat Number   : " + input , 0, 290);    
                g.drawLine(380, 310, 0, 310);
                g.drawString("Ticket Number : " + printable.getTicket_entry_number(), 0, 350);
                g.drawString("Ticket Type   : " + printable.getTicket_type(), 0, 370);
                g.drawString("Movie Name    : " + printable.getMovie_name(), 0, 390);
                g.drawString("Date          : " + printable.getShow_date(), 0, 410);
                g.drawString("Time          : " + printable.getSpecific_time(), 0, 430);
                g.drawString("Theater       : " + printable.getTheater(), 0, 450);
                g.drawString("Cinema Room   : " + printable.getCinema_room(), 0, 470);
                g.drawString("Cost          : " + printable.getCost(), 0, 490);
                g.drawString("Cashier       : " + printable.getCashier(), 0, 510);
                g.drawString("Printed On    : " + GetStuff.getCurrentDate(), 0, 530);
                g.drawString("Seat Number   : " + input, 0, 550);
                g.drawLine(380, 570, 0, 570);
                // String combo = "Combo";
                BufferedImage img = null;
                g.setFont(new Font("Eras Bold ITC", Font.ROMAN_BASELINE, 20)); 
                if(printable.getTicket_type().equals("VIP")){
                    g.drawString("VIP SEATING", 0, 610);
                    g.drawString("DRINK + SNACK", 0, 630);
                    try {

                        String number = Integer.toString(printable.getTicket_entry_number());
                        Barcode barCode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(number);
                        img = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barCode);
                        //ImageIO.read(new File("image/logo.png"));
                    } catch (BarcodeException | OutputException e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Failed to Load Image");
                    }


                    int w = img.getWidth(null);
                    int h = img.getHeight(null);
                    BufferedImage bi = new
                            BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
                    g = bi.getGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
                    /* Draw the image, applying the filter */
                    g2d.drawImage(bi, null, 0, 650);
                }else if(printable.getTicket_type().equals("Combo")){

                    g.drawString("FREE SODA", 0, 610);
                    g.drawString("FREE PORPCORN", 0, 630);
                    try {

                        String number = Integer.toString(printable.getTicket_entry_number());
                        Barcode barCode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(number);
                        img = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barCode);
                        //ImageIO.read(new File("image/logo.png"));
                    } catch (BarcodeException | OutputException e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Failed to Load Image");
                    }


                    int w = img.getWidth(null);
                    int h = img.getHeight(null);
                    BufferedImage bi = new
                            BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
                    g = bi.getGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
                    /* Draw the image, applying the filter */
                    g2d.drawImage(bi, null, 0, 650);

                }else{
                    try {

                        String number = Integer.toString(printable.getTicket_entry_number());
                        Barcode barCode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(number);
                        img = BarcodeImageHandler.getImage(barCode);
                        //ImageIO.read(new File("image/logo.png"));
                    } catch (BarcodeException | OutputException e) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Failed to Load Image");
                    }


                    int w = img.getWidth(null);
                    int h = img.getHeight(null);
                    BufferedImage bi = new
                            BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
                    g = bi.getGraphics();
                    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
                    /* Draw the image, applying the filter */
                    g2d.drawImage(bi, null, 0, 590);

                }

                BufferedImage img2 = null;
                try {
                    img2 = ImageIO.read(new File("images/logo.png"));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

                int wi = 150; //img.getWidth(null);
                int hi = 50; //img.getHeight(null);
                BufferedImage bin = new
                        BufferedImage(wi, hi, BufferedImage.TRANSLUCENT);
                g = bin.getGraphics();
                g.drawImage(img2, 0, 0, null);
                /* Draw the image, applying the filter */
                g2d.drawImage(bin, null, 0, 26);



                book.append(this, pf);
                // tell the caller that this page is part
                // of the printed document
                return PAGE_EXISTS;

            }
        };
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

        job.setPrintable(b);



        if (job.printDialog())
        {


            //job.setPageable(book);

            job.print();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;



}
```

}

Comment: Could be an issue with the printer driver. Is the printer capable of printing within the white areas? Can you do so from other applications? Can you do so from other _Java_ applications?

Comment: Same case with my other java applications, even the hello world example is cut but other application i designed with  vb.net work perfectly.